# Android - Leadbolt HTML banner

Tags: android, html, webview, banner, leadbolt

I'm trying to integrate a Leadbolt HTML banner ad (320x50) into my Android application. The problem is that whenever I click on the banner, the page it leads to opens in place of the ad (i.e. it is clipped to 320x50) instead of opening in fullscreen. I would expect that at least the most trivial implementation (a plain fullscreen WebView with the standard Leadbolt HTML snippet) should work, but that is not the case... Any suggestions?

The HTML code:

```
<html><body style="margin:0px;padding:0px"><script type="text/javascript" src="http://ad.leadboltads.net/show_app_ad.js?section_id=XXXXXXXX"></script></body></html>
```

Comment: how does your ad even show up? my leadbolt ad does not even show up when I use the same script tag in my html... 
one thing though, that I add the banner tag via js functions after the html is loaded